# ElasticSearch Aggregation within aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am trying to write aggregation script for ElasticSearch.

Document Type:

```
{
  Score: [1 , null, 3]
},
{
  Score: [2, 4, null + 3]
}
```

I want to get an average of all Scores. I wrote simple Aggregation which returns

```
(1 + 3 + 2 + 4 + 3) / 5 = 2.6
```

But i want to perform Average of Score for each document and then average that.
for e.g.

```
[1 + 3] / 2 (# of scores in first document)
+
[2 + 4 + 3] / 3 (# of scores in second document)
= (2 + 3) / 2 (# of documents)
= 2.5
```

Comment: Hi @Sagar, have you checked my answer? has been of any use to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this query is what you are looking for:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "avg_by_group": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "score"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "overall_avg": {
      "avg_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "group_by_id>avg_by_group"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Explanation

The `group_by_id` aggregation will create a bucket for each document, and the `avg_by_group` sub-aggregation will calculate the average `score` for each bucket/document. Finally, the `overall_avg` pipeline aggregation will calculate the average of the averages.